# How to continue past bugs in the Forsworn Conspiracy?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

As it is known, [the Forsworn Conspiracy](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Forsworn_Conspiracy) is the buggiest quest in the game.

In my case, what happened is that Eltrys was dead from the first place. I want to continue with the quest, and get jailed into the mine, ... but I don't know how to.

I tried console commands like `setstage MS01 100` to finish the quest, but if I do that, I get "teleported" to the entrance of the mine-jail (as it is supposed to) but nobody opens the door. So I get stuck in a 2x2m room. I tried going stage by stage in the Forsworn Conspiracy, but it doesn't work.  The only way of completing it is manually setting it to 100. But then, how can I continue?

Has anyone had this problem?  How did you solve it?  If it matters, I'm playing on the PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[In addition](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Forsworn_Conspiracy#Bugs) to using `setstage MS01 100`, you should use `setstage MS02 0` to start the next sequence.

Alternatively you can use `setstage MS02 10`, commit a crime and get caught, which should continue the quest like it's supposed to.

Comment: As a side note, [Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages wiki has better bug listing than wikia](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Forsworn_Conspiracy)